# ASIHttpRequest setProgress: called only with a value of 0.0 and 1.0

Tags: iphone, ios, http, asihttprequest, progress

I was woking on [YouTube Resumable Uploads](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_resumable_uploads#Sending_a_Resumable_Upload_API_Request)

The progress jumps from 0 to 1 with ASIHTTPRequest. 
Here is my code :

```
-(void)uploadVideoFile:(NSDictionary *) params
{
    if(_location && _location.length != 0)
    {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:_location];
        ASIFormDataRequest *theRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [theRequest setRequestMethod:@"PUT"];

        NSString *length = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld",[WSKSharerHelper fileSizeWithPath:_filePath]];
        [theRequest addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type"    value:@"video/quicktime"];
        [theRequest addRequestHeader:@"Content-Length"  value:length];

        [theRequest appendPostDataFromFile:_filePath];

        theRequest.delegate = self;
        theRequest.uploadProgressDelegate = self;
        theRequest.timeOutSeconds = 100;
        [[ASIManager manager] addRequest:theRequest];
        [[ASIManager manager] startQueue];
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) instead.

Comment: For some reasons, I can only use ASIHttpRequest now.

Answer (score 0):

```
theRequest.showAccurateProgress = YES;
```

This will turn on accurate progress tracking. Please note that it will impact performance in some cases. See [the docs](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) for more information.